# Why examples of the order of algebraic computations do not agree with calculator results?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

This my first lesson in Algebra

I replaced the dot signs with x. I've never seen times done with a dot before

Lesson taken from [MathPlanet](http://www.mathplanet.com/education/pre-algebra/introducing-algebra/operations-in-the-correct-order)

#### Operations in the correct order

When you are faced with a mathematical expression that has several operations or parentheses, the solution may be affected by the order in which you tackle the operations. For example, take the expression

```
 4 x 7 - 2
```

If we do the multiplication first, we arrive at the following answer:

```
 28 - 2 = 26
```

If instead we begin by substracting, we get:

```
4 x 5= 20
```

---

I'm even more confused by this! When I try to reproduce what they are talking about I press the buttons on the calculator in this order (now * is times x on windows calc)

```
4 * 7 - 2 = //I get 28 that worked well

2 - 7 * 4 = // -20
```

I really don't understand their example, How does it work how they say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Different calculators work differently. Simpler models evaluate operations one at a time, as they are entered. For them, `2-7*4` means

1. Calculate `2-7`
2. Multiply the result by `4`

They do not understand   complex formulas: they just see one operation at a time. With such calculators, you have to keep track of the order of operations yourself: first do `7*4` and then subtract the result from `2`.

More sophisticated calculators can evaluate more complex formulas, and for them `2-7*4 = -26`.

You can tell that your calculator is of the simpler kind if after entering `2-7*` you already see `-5` on the screen: the calculator does not wait to see a formula, since it is not capable of parsing it anyway.

Comment: the javascript console i think is better!

Comment: Yes, it parses formulas. As does any kind of console where you (1) type the formula; (2) hit the return key to get it evaluated.

Answer (score 3):

The convention is that if there are no brackets multiplication is done before addition. Things in brackets are done first. Subtraction is a form of addition (add the negative). Division is a form of multiplication (multiply by the reciprocal).

$4\times 7 -2=(4 \times 7)-2=28-2=26$

$4\times (7-2) = 4\times 5=20$

If you change the order of things to get $2-4\times 7$ you won't get the same result.

Answer (score 2):

Remember this PEMDAS.

Please Excuse My Aunt Sally.

P
 Parentheses first

E
 Exponents (ie Powers and Square Roots, etc.)

MD
 Multiplication and  Division (left-to-right)

AS
 Addition and Subtraction (left-to-right)

Comment: But there aren't any parentheses in the lesson!

Comment: E Exponents (ie Powers and Square Roots, etc.) there is no note for this or point to remember?